# Quit makefile from inside a shell code line

Tags: bash, makefile, gnu-make

How to quit makefile from inside its running shell code, as

```
@if [ $$m = 'y' ] ;then exit ;fi
```

is exiting shell instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any command that will return non-zero status will stop the Makefile (or the current target when running with '-k'). There is no need to wrap inside if (unless this is part of a scriptlet that contain multiple commands.

```
target:
    ...
    [ "$$m" = 'y' ]
    ...
```

Note that the variable 'm' must be environment variable or set by previous command that is part of the same command sequence. It can NOT be set in a separate command line:

```
correct:
    m=... ; [ "$$m" = 'y' ]

wrong:
    m=...
    [ "$$m" = 'y' ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `exit`, try `exit 1`.